# calculate the difference of each values of array

Tags: php

Newbie here in PHP programming. I have some question regarding arrays. How can I get the difference between adjacent values in an array?

```
$value = array(2, 5, 9, 10, 19);
```

How do I get the difference between the 2 and 5? Then 9 and 5? Then 10 and 9, then 19 and 10?
The reason I want to get the difference is to draw a stack graph. And each stack will depend on each difference.

### Update:

Hi, sorry guys, totally lost on this one. It seems that I can't do it the way I want. Please click [here](http://img522.imageshack.us/img522/2360/graphnu.jpg) to see the similar stacked graph I want. How do I create a scale for my arrays so that when I plot the stacked graph it will automatically adjust to its value?

Here is the code that I am trying to use.

```
<?php
$img_width=200;
$img_height=425; 
$img=imagecreatetruecolor($img_width,$img_height);
$bar_color=imagecolorallocate($img,0,64,128);
$line_color=imagecolorallocate($img,220,220,220);
imagefilledrectangle($img,$x1,$y1,$x2,$y2,$bar_color);

$value = array(116,160,210,269,325,425);
for ($i = 1, $n = count($value); $i < $n; $i++) {
    $diffs[] = $value[$i] - $value[$i-1];
    imageline($img,0,$value[$i]-$value[$i-1],$img_width,$value[$i]-$value[$i-1],$line_color);
}
header("Content-type:image/png");
imagepng($img);
?>
```

I appreciate all your help.

Comment: Relate: [Subtract previous variable with current variable in php while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53645930/2943403) and [Subtract the preceding value from the current value using php while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34648196/2943403)

Comment: Also: [PHP array values subtraction until the last value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57864158/2943403)

Answer (score 8):

Just use a simple `for` loop:

```
$diffs = array();
for ($i = 1, $n = count($value); $i < $n; $i++) {
    $diffs[] = $value[$i] - $value[$i-1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Gumbo you added **$diffs = array();** it has to be **$value**

```
<?php
$value = array(2,5,9,10,19);
for ($i = 1, $n = count($value); $i < $n; $i++) {
    $diffs[] = $value[$i] - $value[$i-1];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($diffs);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: No, I just initiated the `$diffs` array.

Comment: Yes but you used $n = count($value); and the variable that had the array numbers was $diffs.

Comment: thanks for the complete detail Vlad. I will try this suggestion.

Comment: What? No, it was always `$value` that held the values as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function and passed the original array to the 2nd parameter, and a modified array (first element removed) to the 3rd parameter. [abs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php) will return the absolute value. *This solution will take care of single element input, unordered elements input and even negative numbers elements input*.

Can be tested online on [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/8As7q).

```
<?php

$result = array_map(function ($v, $y) {
    return abs($y - $v);
}, $array_values, array_slice($array_values, 1));

array_pop($result); // to remove (kinda-fix) for the last difference
```

**Output for different inputs:**

1.) `$array_values = array('2', '6', '16', '27');` for multiple elements:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 10
    [2] => 11
)
```

2.) `$array_values = array('2');` for single element: Empty array.

```
Array
(
)
```