# Subtract the preceding value from the current value using php while loop

Tags: php

Hi i have 5 rows in my table like

```
id  value
1   10
2   25
3   30
4   40
```

now i want to display the value in table format like

**10**  [15 (ie. 25 -10)]  **25** [15]  **30** [10]   **40**

Comment: Your question is not clear. You may want to re-write it. And maybe give more obvious examples.

Comment: 10 [15 (ie. 25 -10)] 25 [15] 30 [10] 40 ??

Comment: and question title is also invalid

Comment: can you show us your while loop code??

Comment: base on what you want to get.  Should it be `10 [15] 25 [5] 30 [10] 40`?

Comment: are you trying to subtract the preceding value from the current value?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `foreach` like as

```
$arr = array(10,25,30,40);

foreach($arr as $k => $v){
    echo $v;
    if(isset($arr[$k+1])){
        echo "[",$arr[$k+1] - $v,"]";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
10[15]
25[5]
30[10]
40
```

Comment: i am sorry, i didn't refresh the page after checking, u have won. :) and earn my vote. cheers

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what actually you want but here is my answer:

```
$yourArr = array(10,25,30,40);

$i = 0;
foreach ($yourArr as $key => $value) {
    //$m = next($yourArr);
    echo $value;
    if(isset($yourArr[$i+1]))
    echo " [ " .($yourArr[$i+1] - $value)." ] ";

$i++;
}
```

**Result:**

```
10 [ 15 ] 25 [ 5 ] 30 [ 10 ] 40
```

Please note that if you avoid to add `isset()` check than you will get the **undefined offset** error for last index.