# PHP Array: Calculate difference among values in same array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to compute the difference between all values in an array and store them (the differences) in a single array.

An ideal example would be something like this:

```
<?php

$data = array('1', '5', '12');

// Compute the difference between each value with another value.

?>
```

And then I like to have the following results in an array:

```
4, 11, 7
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: What do you mean for difference, next, previous, absolute value, sum of all elements?

Comment: @MauricioFlorez I mean the difference between 5 & 1 (which is 4). And then the difference between 1 & 12 (which is 11).. and so on.

Comment: Related: [calculate the difference of each values of array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4298472/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$data = array('1', '5', '12');
$differences=[];
for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++){
    for($j=$i+1;$j<count($data);$j++){
        $differences[]=abs($data[$i]-$data[$j]);
    }
}
print_r($differences);
```

results in

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 11
    [2] => 7
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this https://3v4l.org/9oiqs

```
$data = [1, 5, 12, 15, 20, 25,];

function getDifferences($aValues)
{
    $aDiff = [];
    $iSize = count($aValues);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $iSize; $i++)
    {
        for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $iSize; $j++)
        {
            $aDiff[$aValues[$i]][] = abs($aValues[$i] - $aValues[$j]);
        }
    }
    return $aDiff;
}

function printDifferences($aValues){
    foreach ($aValues as $iNumber => $aDiffs){
        echo "Differences for $iNumber: " . implode(', ', $aDiffs) . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$aDiff = getDifferences($data);
printDifferences($aDiff);
```

> **Result**
>   Differences for 1: 4, 11, 14, 19, 24
>   Differences for 5: 7, 10, 15, 20
>   Differences for 12: 3, 8, 13
>   Differences for 15: 5, 10
>   Differences for 20: 5

Comment: Little variation from @musashii