# PHP Check if a number is in sequence but with one missing

Tags: php

I can find if an array of values are in sequence using:

```
    sort($arr);
    if ($arr == range($arr[0], $arr[count($arr)-1])) {
      return true;
    }
```

So anything like `1,2,3,4,5`, `6,7,8` will result in true but how can I find a number in sequence but with one number missing? So the expected output would be:

```
2,3,5,6 = true
2,5,6,8 = false
3,6,10,16 = false
5,7,8,9,10,11 = true
```

Comment: is step in sequence always 1?

Comment: You could use the sum property Sn=n*(a1 + a2)/2   if the step is always 1.

Comment: @Alive to Die How do you figure that is a duplicate?

Comment: Do you mean with sequence that is possible the skip 1 number ? for example `1,3 = true` and `1,4 = false` ?

Comment: @sayou Yeah that is correct.

Comment: you have to find out successive difference of values and if it's 1 or 2  then it means you have sequential values. check here:-https://stackoverflow.com/a/4298486/4248328

Comment: since your question is not clear there are 3 or 4 answers are matching your requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just checked this and it matches the outputs you expect from your original question

```
function skippedValue($arr) {
sort($arr);
return sizeof(array_diff(range($arr[0], $arr[count($arr)-1]), $arr)) == 1;
}

var_dump(skippedValue([2,3,5,6]));        // true
var_dump(skippedValue([2,5,6,8]));        // false
var_dump(skippedValue([3,6,10,16]));      // false
var_dump(skippedValue([5,7,8,9,10,11])); //true
```

result: bool(true) bool(false) bool(false) bool(true)

Comment: This does not confirm the *order* of the values in any way, but assuming you'll `sort` the values at some point… yeah, this is good.

Comment: @deceze good point, I have assumed that it's been sorted already (as in the OP) I'll edit the function just in case!

Answer (score 5):

Algorithmically rather verbose, but works:

```
function checkAlmostSequential(array $seq, $maxSkips = 1) {
    $skipped = 0;

    for ($i = 0, $num = $seq[0]; $i < count($seq); $num++) {
        if ($num == $seq[$i]) {
            $i++;
        } else {
            $skipped++;
        }

        if ($skipped > $maxSkips) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

var_dump(checkAlmostSequential([2,3,5,6]));        // true
var_dump(checkAlmostSequential([2,5,6,8]));        // false
var_dump(checkAlmostSequential([3,6,10,16]));      // false
var_dump(checkAlmostSequential([5,7,8,9,10,11]));  // true
```

Comment: Note: if you *require* one number to be missing, alter this to `return $skipped == $maxSkips` at the end…

Answer (score 4):

Small function to verify if is sequence

```
function verifySequence($arr){
sort($arr);
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($arr) - 1; $i++){
    $j = $i + 1;
    if( (($arr[$i] + 1) !== $arr[$j]) && (($arr[$i] + 2) !== $arr[$j])){
       return false;
    }
}
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check using good old `for` loop

```
function missingItemChecker($arr, $max_missing = 1){
    sort($arr);
    $check_arr = range($arr[0], $arr[count($arr)-1]);
    $missing = 0;
    $len = count($check_arr);
    $j = 0;
    for($i =  0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        if( $check_arr[$i] !== ($arr[$j] ?? false) ){
            $missing++;
        } else { $j++; }
    }
    return $missing == $max_missing;
}
```

**Edit**: The Logic here is,

1. Sort to get the Minimum and Maximum in the range using `sort($arr)`.
2. Create an array of the actual sequence `$check_arr = range()`.
3. Maintain a count of the numbers missing with `$missing`.
4. Loop through the real sequence to and check against the input array
   to get the number of the missing elements.
5. If the number of missing elements is equal to the max allowed missing elements, the sequence has more than 1 numbers missing, else its either complete or only one element is missing.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that the OP can learn from it

Comment: `bool(false)` for all inputs ?

Comment: @Bira I think its a bad day for me, but check it now all the silly mistakes are fixed

Comment: When trying these inputs: [1,2,3], [1,2,4], [1,2,4,5,7], I get outputs: true, false, false respectfully.  The second one matches the OP's requirements.  The others do not.  That's my interpretation of the question, look for a sequence with only one item missing.

Comment: @Progrock You are right. The question was not clear enough, I have edited the question as well as my answer.

Comment: @Aakash More The question was always a sequence of numbers with one missing, don't see how that is not clear. None of these sequences [1,2,3], [1,2,4], [1,2,4,5,7] are correct if they return true, false, false except the last one since it has two numbers missing.

Comment: @Hasen add another example like `1,2,3,4,5 false`. I have also edited the code.

Answer (score 2):

Having misunderstood the question initially I hope this now does as expected - not the easiest to read perhaps.

```
$a=[1,2,5,6];
$b=[34,35,36,37,38];
$c=[5,7,8,9,10,15];
$d=[1,3,4,5,6,8];
$e=[3,6,10,16];
$f=[2,3,5,6];

function is_semi_sequential( $a ){
    rsort( $a );
    $c=[];
    for( $i=count( $a )-1; $i >= 0; $i-- ){
        if( isset( $a[ $i ] ) && isset( $a[ $i+1 ] ) && $a[ $i ] - $a[ $i + 1 ]!=1 ) $c[]=( $a[ $i ] - $a[ $i + 1 ] );
    }
    return count( $c ) <= 1 && array_sum( $c ) <= 2 ? true : false;
}


echo is_semi_sequential( $a ) ? 'sequential' : 'non-sequential';
echo '<br />';

echo is_semi_sequential( $b ) ? 'sequential' : 'non-sequential';
echo '<br />';

echo is_semi_sequential( $c ) ? 'sequential' : 'non-sequential';
echo '<br />';

echo is_semi_sequential( $d ) ? 'sequential' : 'non-sequential';
echo '<br />';

echo is_semi_sequential( $e ) ? 'sequential' : 'non-sequential';
echo '<br />';

echo is_semi_sequential( $f ) ? 'sequential' : 'non-sequential';
```

Outputs:

```
non-sequential
sequential
non-sequential
non-sequential
non-sequential
sequential
```

Answer (score 0):

If we count items that are one value more than the previous, the total will be two less than the amount of items for sequences with only one missing member.

```
<?php
// Assuming zero indexed and sequential keys in input array.
function missing_only_one_incremental_value_in_sequence(array $nums)
{
    $count     = count($nums);
    $seq_count = 0;
    for($i=1; $i<$count; $i++)
        if($nums[$i]==$nums[$i-1]+1)
            $seq_count++;

    return $seq_count == $count-2;
}

var_dump(missing_only_one_incremental_value_in_sequence([2,3,5,6]));
var_dump(missing_only_one_incremental_value_in_sequence([2,5,6,8]));
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

For more sample inputs and outputs see here: https://3v4l.org/PFQ5d