# PHP array values subtraction until the last value

Tags: php

I have an array

```
$arr = [20,22,29,40,67,35,98,200,205,220];
```

In this we subtract 1st value from second,second from third, third from fourth value and so on.
After subtracting this way we get new values. These new values should follow the same procedure until there 
remain single value at the end. First time subtracting array values is simple but new values subtraction looks
difficult for me. Thanks.

I expect the output

```
2, 7, 11, 27, -32, 63, 102, 5, 15
5, 4, 16, -59, 95, 39, -97, 10
-1, 12, -75, 154, -56, -136, 107
13, -87, 229, -210, -80, 243,
-100, 316, -439, 130, 323
416, -755, 569, 193
-1171, 1324, -376
2495, -1700
-4195
```

Comment: Great! So what have you [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)?

Comment: First array I have subtracted and the values I get placed in new array. How I repeat the same procedure with this new array seems difficult for me?

Comment: I have solution for it, but just try with nested loop. Show us code that you have tried then we will show you correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will go with recursion

```
<?php

$arr = [20,22,29,40,67,35,98,200,205,220];

function subArrayValues($array)
{
    static $round = 0; //just to not output first array
    if (count($array) < 2){
        echo $array[0];
        return;
    }
    $prevVal = null;
    $newArray = [];
    foreach ($array as $val){

        if ($prevVal !== null){
            $result =  $val - $prevVal;
            $newArray[] = $result;
        }
        $prevVal = $val;
   }
   if ($round > 0) echo implode(",", $array) . "\n";
   $round++;
   subArrayValues($newArray);

}

subArrayValues($arr);
```

This outputs

```
2,7,11,27,-32,63,102,5,15
5,4,16,-59,95,39,-97,10
-1,12,-75,154,-56,-136,107
13,-87,229,-210,-80,243
-100,316,-439,130,323
416,-755,569,193
-1171,1324,-376
2495,-1700
-4195
```

Live demo https://3v4l.org/JO3RX

Answer (score 3):

Below is the solution with nested loop.

```
$arr = [20,22,29,40,67,35,98,200,205,220];
$result = [];
$count = count($arr);
while($count > 0){
    for($index = 0; $index < $count-1; $index++){
        $arr[$index] = $arr[$index + 1] - $arr[$index];
    }
    unset($arr[$index]);
    $count--;
    echo implode(', ', $arr). '<br/>';
}
```

After writing down above solution I felt this can be achieved with single loop also. so I got below

```
$arr = [20,22,29,40,67,35,98,200,205,220];
$result = [];
$count = count($arr);

for($index = 0; $index < $count-1; $index++){

    $arr[$index] = $arr[$index + 1] - $arr[$index];

    if($index == $count - 2){
        unset($arr[$index+1]);
        echo implode(', ', $arr). '<br>';
        $count--;
        $index = -1;
    }
}
```

People will prefer first nested solution because it is lot easier to understand compare to second single array solution.

[Helping Links1](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&ei=xi53XeHKIubTz7sPvpCIkAQ&q=nested+loops+php&oq=nested+loops+php&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i30j0i5i30l2j0i8i30l6.4301.4895..6124...0.2..0.119.237.0j2......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i13j0i8i7i30j0i13i30j0i13i5i30j0i8i13i30.Z0e_B55qu68&ved=0ahUKEwjhxfWrvcXkAhXm6XMBHT4IAkIQ4dUDCAs&uact=5)
[Helping Link2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)
[Helping Link3](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: Man I took sometime to figure out why your second solution doesn't work, you need to set the index to -1 `$index = -1` instead of `$index=0` because at the end of the loop it will be incremented by `$index++` so it will be 1, not 0 . Nice work

Answer (score 2):

You can build a recursive function by using `for` loop

```
function subTractReccursive($a){
  for($i=0;$i<count($a)-1;$i++){
    $c[] = $a[$i+1]-$a[$i];
  }
  echo implode ('  ',$c)."\n";
  if(count($c) > 1){
    subTractReccursive($c);
  }
  return;
}
$a = [20,22,29,40,67,35,98,200,205,220];
subTractReccursive($a);
```

Working example : https://3v4l.org/ehD26